# Using "image" from crates.io to make an image into a grayscale version of itself

Tags: rust, rust-crates

```
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::wasm_bindgen;
use web_sys::console::log_1 as log;
use base64::{Engine as _, engine::{general_purpose}};
use image::{load_from_memory, imageops};




#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn grayscaleImg(encoded_file: &str) {

    log(&"Grayscale called".into());

    let base64_to_vector = general_purpose::STANDARD.decode(encoded_file).unwrap();
    log(&"Image decoded".into());

    let img = load_from_memory(&base64_to_vector);
    log(&"Image Loaded".into());
    
    let gray_img = imageops::grayscale(img);
    log(&"Grayscale effect applied".into());

}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Result<DynamicImage, ImageError>: GenericImageView` is not satisfied
  --> src\lib.rs:21:20
   |
21 |     let gray_img = imageops::grayscale(&img);
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `GenericImageView` is not implemented for `Result<DynamicImage, ImageError>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `GenericImageView`:
             DynamicImage
             ImageBuffer<P, Container>
             View<Buffer, P>
             ViewMut<Buffer, P>
             image::image::SubImageInner<I>
```

i am trying to use the imageops::grayscale to make an image into a grayscale version of itself, the image comes from posting an image to a website however i keep getting different errors even though it seems as though im using the crate correctly the error says

Comment: if you need more information to help me with the question please by all means, I havent really posted any questions before and im sure I am not giving the full picture but im not sure what else I need to include

Comment: [`load_from_memory`](https://docs.rs/image/0.24.6/image/fn.load_from_memory.html) returns a result which might be an error. You need to add [error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error.html). The YOLO way to go on about it is [`let img = load_from_memory(…).expect_throw("Undecodable image data");`](https://docs.rs/wasm-bindgen/latest/wasm_bindgen/trait.UnwrapThrowExt.html#example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`image::load_from_memory()` returns a `Result<DynamicImage, ImageError>`, but `image::imageops::grayscale()` requires a `DynamicImage`.

You can either `unwrap()` the returned `Result` type, which means your program will crash if the returned value is an error, or you can handle the error using a `match` statement.

Here is how to do it using `unwrap()`:

```rust
pub fn grayscaleImg(encoded_file: &str) {
    let base64_to_vector = general_purpose::STANDARD.decode(encoded_file).unwrap();
    let img = load_from_memory(&base64_to_vector).unwrap();
    let gray_img = imageops::grayscale(&img);
}
```

And here is how to do it using `match`:

```rust
pub fn grayscaleImg(encoded_file: &str) {
    let base64_to_vector = general_purpose::STANDARD.decode(encoded_file).unwrap();
    let img = match load_from_memory(&base64_to_vector) {
        Ok(img) => img,
        Err(error) => {
            // Handle error here.
        }
    };
    let gray_img = imageops::grayscale(&img);
}
```

Comment: wow I literally missed it by a hair thank you so much I really appreciate it